# select both null and not null values of different column and row values

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about SQL; please help me.

```
COLUMN NAME1    COLUMN NAME2
----------------------------    
A                  1
A                  2
A                  NULL
B                  3
C                  NULL
```

This is my table from that I have to select that not null values of A and B and also select NULL value of C.

That is if A has NULL values only and C has NOT NULL values only means I have to select NULL values of A and not null values of C.

That is if A has both NULL and NOT NULL values means I want NOT NULL only of A and C has NULL values means I want NULL values of C.

At the same time if C has NULL AND NOT NULL values means I want the NOT NULL values of C.

Please help me soon. I am waiting

Comment: [What have **YOU** tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Please can you show us what output you're expecting (as a table) - I'm finding your narrative difficult to follow. You might need to add more sample data as well to show different combinations.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you want to do in the end? Maybe an other approach is a better solution.